# Can a DataStage job be viewed without access to a DataStage installation

Tags: debugging, datastage

I am tasked to replace an ETL process that used to run in DataStage.  I have used DataStage in the past and would be able to review it for replication if I could view it.

I have the extracted jobs in version control, is there a way to view the job without access to DataStage?  (If needed, I could request new extracts)

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for a [job report](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=designs-generating-job-report) - that is a picture of the job with a printed logic for each stage in form of a html page. This might be enough to rebuild the job. There is no access to a free DataStage fat client.

Comment: The job report sounds like it would help, Thank you.  I have put in the request.